Flowise Error: vectorsService.upsertVector - Error: TypeError: fetch failed when upsert
I am doing a upsert to vector database.
Flowise UI error
Over at server side it was mentioned the embedding failed
Flowise Server Error
Anyone encountered this while working with Flowise?
Is there anything I need to install at server or any configuration I missed out?

It seems you don't have a Splitter attached to your PDF File Loader.
Check the limits of your Embeddings Node Model.
I can't make out which one you're using exactly in the picture, but for Ollama you can find them here.
Make sure you don't exceed it's limits when choosing a splitter node / chunking Strategy for your File. You can find some Information on that provided by Flowise here.
HTH
